# swedish characters are missing while displaying on html form

Tags: html

I am trying to fetch the swedish content from another site. I am able to fetch the data but the Swedish characters(ÅÖÄ) are missing. Swedish Content that I have added directly has no issue to display as i have added the meta-tag. The issue is when i am trying to display the data from another site. Is it possible to fix this issue. I do not have any access to other site.

Comment: your site doesn't use the same encoding of the other site. this is not an html problem. add more info about what you are doing

Comment: how are you trying to get this data? You have provided no code of what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

To take into account Swedish characters, you need to set the `charset` to `UTF-8`. An example from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta) is:

```
<!-- In HTML5 -->
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Defining the charset in HTML4 --> 
<!-- Note: This is invalid in HTML5 -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

The meta tag goes in the `<head>` tag like so:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
</html>
```

To quote from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta):

> [charset] declares the character encoding used of the page. It can be locally overridden using the lang attribute on any element. This
>   attribute is a literal string and must be one of the preferred MIME
>   names for a character encoding as defined by the IANA. Though the
>   standard doesn't request a specific character encoding, it gives some
>   recommendations:
>
> - Authors are encouraged to use UTF-8.
> - Authors should not use ASCII-incompatible encodings (i.e. those that don't map the 8-bit code points 0x20 to 0x7E to the Unicode
>     0x0020 to 0x007E code points) as these represent a security risk:
>     browsers not supporting them may interpret benign content as HTML
>     Elements. This is the case of at least the following charsets:
>     JIS_C6226-1983, JIS_X0212-1990, HZ-GB-2312, JOHAB, the ISO-2022
>     family, and the EBCDIC family.
> - Authors must not use CESU-8, UTF-7, BOCU-1 and SCSU, also falling in that category and not intended to be used on the web.
>     Cross-scripting attacks with some of these encodings have been
>     documented.
> - Authors should not use UTF-32 because not all HTML5 encoding algorithms can distinguish it from UTF-16.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is also a link on UTF-8.

**Note: if for some reason `UTF-8` encoding is not working for your characters, try `charset="ISO-8859-1"`*

Comment: "set the charset to UTF-8": Not exactly, charset _documents_ the character set and encoding used by the document. It should be set to that, whatever it is. If the document is generated or saved by a library, it would set that value itself based the encoding being used to save the file. But, yes, if using a text editor, do save it as UTF-8 after typing in UTF-8 into the tag.